How to have the left padding/margin be 0 so that this columnwidth image does not have extra margin/padding on right?
How to have the left padding/margin be 0 so that this columnwidth image does not have extra margin/padding on right?

\subsubsection{AI3D Benchmark Card}

The AI3D Foundation produces a ``Benchmark Card" that allows for succinct visual comparison of the mesh produced by each model, including the hardware used and inference time expended for each service endpoint.

\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{img/benchmarkcard2.jpg}


Maybe the indentation. Try \noindent before \includegraphics. If it doesn't work, provide a minimal working example (MWE).

Note that figure automatically resets \parindent=0pt, at least for most classes.

You haven't specified which document class you employ, but it would appear that you're employing a class that tells LaTeX to insert horizontal whitespace (generally governed by a length parameter called \parindent) at the start of a (semantic) paragraph. In both Plain-TeX and LaTeX, an all-blank line creates a paragraph break. Because the image that's inserted by the
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{img/benchmarkcard2.jpg}

instruction is -- semantically speaking -- a paragraph, it too gets indented by default.
What to do? If you just want to suppress the insertion of whitespace at the start of this particular (semantic) paragraph, preface it with \noindent, while still leaving an all-blank line before \noindent. On the other hand, if you want to suppress this insertion of whitespace globally, i.e., for the entire document, I suggest you insert the instruction
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

in the preamble.
